# Robotframework DateTime Library

Tags: datetime, robotframework

Can i install robotframework DateTime Library using robotframework v2.8.3?
If so can anyone give me a link for it. Thanks!

I tried using the Get Time to do it but the use is not sufficient for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to install the library as it is one of the Standard Libraries. In order to use it, you can either specify it in your settings like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DateTime
```

or import it in your test case using:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Import Library    DateTime
```

For clarity I would prefer the first variant. [See 2.8.3 documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.8.3/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-test-libraries)

Comment: In addition to the above example it should be stated that this library comes standard with Robot Framework and does not need to be seperately downloaded.

Comment: @A.Kootstra Good hint, I added a note

Comment: @Würgspaß DateTime library is new in Robot Framework 2.8.5. But i am trying to use it on 2.8.3.

Comment: @ProPlayerr That's true. In that case the only way I know is to upgrade to 2.8.5

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DateTime

*** Test Cases ***
    ${currentTime}=  Get Time
    Log To Console  ${currentTime}
```